# Como ler linha de arquivo .txt a partir do índice 0

Tags: c++, lógica

Possuo o seguinte trecho de código que lê linha por linha de um arquivo texto, fim até início da *string*. Como devo alterá-lo, para que tal ação ocorra de maneira inversa?

```
while (getline (entrada, linha)){
    int tam_linha = linha.size(); /* Tamaho da linha, caracateres por linha */

    for(int i=tam_linha-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if(linha[i] == ' ' && linha[i-1] == linha[i])
        {
            linha.erase(linha.begin()+i);                    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Inversa seria do início (linha 1, índice 0) até o fim (linha x, índice y)?

Comment: Dê uma olhada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035674/how-to-read-line-by-line-or-a-whole-text-file-at-once).

Comment: @CypherPotato sim.

Comment: Qual o propósito de ler a string byte-a-byte ? Um filtro que remove os espaços em branco duplicados ?

Comment: @Lacobus, a intenção é remover excessos de espaços, deixando apenas um espaço entre cada palavra, inicio e fim da linha.

Comment: @Lacobus devo criar uma nova pergunta para esse objetivo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a intenção é ler linha a linha de um arquivo texto filtrando o conteúdo de cada linha com a remoção dos espaços duplos por espaços simples, seguem 2 soluções em C++ utilizando a `STL`:

Utilizando as funções `std::unique()` e `std::string::erase()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool check_double_spaces( char a, char b) { return ((a == b) && (a == ' ')); }

int main()
{
    string linha;
    ifstream entrada("arquivo.txt");

    while( getline( entrada, linha) )
    {
        string::iterator end = unique( linha.begin(), linha.end(), check_double_spaces );

        linha.erase( end, linha.end() );

        cout << linha << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Utilizando as funções `std::string::find()` e `std::string::replace()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string linha;
    ifstream entrada("arquivo.txt");
    size_t idx;

    while( getline( entrada, linha ) )
    {
        while( (idx = linha.find("  ")) != string::npos ) // Dois espaços
            linha.replace( idx, 2, " " ); // Um espaço

        cout << linha << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(void) {
    FILE *ficheiro = fopen("arquivo.txt", "r");
    if(ficheiro == NULL){
        printf("\nErro");
        exit(1);
    }
    char linha[100];
    while(fgets(linha, 100, ficheiro){ //essa função vai ler todo o ficheiro
        printf("\n%s", linha);
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá @clidsaniny, gostaria que as alterações fossem feitas no código mencionado... se possível.

Comment: Olá @luccasrodrigo pela minha visão acho o exemplo dado é mais eficaz para a sua necessidade. Caso queira que um exemplo baseado no seu código, apresenta um ex do ficheiro.txt. Aguardo...

Comment: Olá @clidsaniny agradeço de coração pela disposição, e realmente os exemplos postados atendem a pergunta inicial. Contudo, creio que para solução do problema maior, devo elaborar uma nova pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Outra solução(se é que eu entendi bem o problema) seria você usar regular expressions:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    regex reg("[ ]+");
    string linha;

    while (getline(cin, linha))
        cout << regex_replace(linha, reg, " ") << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Todos os espaços múltiplos vão ser substituídos por apenas um.